# Per-solution Atomineer preferences

Tags: xml-documentation, atomineer

With [Atomineer Pro Doc for VS](https://www.atomineerutils.com/), is it possible to have the (*some?*) settings/preferences saved in the current `$(SolutionDir)` directory? I realize that there is an option to save/use the `prefs.xml` file from locations other than the default by setting the Search Paths under General Settings / Preference Storage, but those look to be requiring absolute paths, while my question is specifically about being able to define such paths *relative* to the current solution/project file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's easy to do this - you just need to use the variable `%projectPath%` or `%solutionPath%` in your search paths to make them relative to the current project or solution.

This allows you to use different settings for every project/solution you work in, and also to check the settings into source control so they can be shared across your team easily.

Comment: Thank you, worked like a charm after I figured out which [custom fies](https://www.atomineerutils.com/rulesguide.php) I needed there.